# Crealty Ender 3 v2; Impossible to calibrate extruder

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, extrusion

I have a Creality Ender 3 v2 3D printer and I recently had trouble while printing.
After some investigations, I found that a piece from the initial plastic extruder was broken (the lever with the roller). I then replaced the whole extruder with the official Creality metal one:

[image: Photo of the Creality metal extruder]

**My problem:**
I tried to calibrate E-steps correctly:

- Disconnect the PTFE tube to remove the nozzle from the problem
- Marking PLA, asking for 10 cm of extrusion and seeing what's left

The PLA filament comes out marked from the extruder (which leads me to believe that tension is enough)

The default E-step value is 93.

The initial result is 0.4 cm left (9.6 cm extruded), and I can do it twice or more, which results in the same measure.
But when I change the E-step value (to 96.9 in this case), I have more than 10 cm extruded. Reducing it to 95 for example results in more than 0.4 cm left (~8 cm extruded).
Then, putting back the E-step value to 93 leads to a different result than initially.

This behavior first made me think of a slip, but it is not apparent, and will not explain the initial reproducibility of the results while not changing the value of the E-step. Moreover, the extruder is new.

**My question:**
Do you have an idea of what could be wrong here?
Assembly error?
Misunderstanding of printer software? Or how to change the E-step value?